# Can not switch Node.js to a default version of my choice

Tags: 18.04, nodejs

When I run `nvm alias default 12.8.0` I get this:

> default -> 12.8.0 (-> v12.8.0)

But when I run `node -v`, I get **v11.9.0** instead

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled everywhere but it seems the command above should work.

Out of curiosity, I tried `nvm alias default 12.8` instead of `nvm alias default 12.8.0` and that solved my problem.

I could guess this is true only if the last digit is 0, otherwise the the full Node.js version should be written.

I faced this problem when I installed a fresh Nuxt.js application and opted to use Eslint which complained about my Node.js version in use, so I had to upgrade and switch to a newer version.

Answer (score 5):

You have the Node.js snap package installed. The Node.js snap package is started with the `node` command. Users can choose from one or more of the currently supported releases and get regular automatic updates directly from NodeSource. Node.js versions 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 and 18 are currently available, with the Snap Store being updated within hours or minutes of a Node.js release.

Users can switch between versions of Node.js at any time without needing to involve additional tools like nvm (Node Version Manager), for example:

```
sudo snap refresh node --channel=8/stable
```

Users can also switch from the stable channel to the edge channel with the following command:

```
sudo snap switch node --edge
```

Then run `node -v` to show the currently selected node version.

#### Node.js LTS schedule

| Release | Status | Codename | Initial release | LTS Start | Maintenance Start | Maintenance End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6.x | EOL | Boron | 2016-04-26 | 2016-10-18 | 2018-04-30 | 2019-04-30 |
| 7.x | EOL |  | 2017-05-30 |  |  | 2017-06-30 |
| 8.x | EOL | Carbon | 2016-10-25 | 2017-10-31 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-12-31 |
| 9.x | EOL |  | 2017-10-01 |  |  | 2018-06-30 |
| 10.x | EOL | Dubnium | 2018-04-24 | 2018-10-30 | 2020-05-19 | 2021-04-30 |
| 11.x | EOL |  | 2018-10-23 |  |  | 2019-06-01 |
| 12.x | Maintenance LTS | Erbium | 2019-04-23 | 2019-10-21 | 2020-11-301 | 2022-04-30 |
| 13.x | EOL |  | 2019-10-22 |  |  | 2020-06-01 |
| 14.x | Maintenance LTS | Fermium | 2020-04-21 | 2020-10-27 | 2021-10-30 | 2023-04-30 |
| 16.x | Active LTS | Gallium | 2021-04-20 | 2021-10-26 | 2022-10-18 | 2024-04-30 |
| 17.x | Current |  | 2021-10-19 |  | 2022-04-01 | 2022-06-01 |
| 18.x | Current |  | 2022-04-19 | 2022-10-25 | 2023-10-18 | 2025-04-30 |